# Developing Apps ON honeycomb devices

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

So here's what I was thinking. Android apps need to be developed on a computer before being installed to a mobile android device. Which was the best solution up until now. Most android enabled devices where phones, and who would want to develop an application on their phone, to small, and wouldn't be convenient.

But since the release of these 10" tablets running android 3.x, wouldn't it be easier to have an app that lets you develop honeycomb specific applications directly on these device ? Is this something that is in development, and if not, why not ? I am fairly new to android, so there are surely some aspect that I am overlooking  that make the matter slightly more complicated.

Comment: "wouldn't it be easier to have an app that lets you develop honeycomb specific applications directly on these device ?" -- you clearly love typing on soft keyboards. :-)

Comment: I should perhaps of mentioned that I'm using the ASUS Eee Pad, with a connectable hard keyboard. My bad ^^"

Comment: Now that I have seen 120 USD tablet (cheap stuff from a brand named 'Wei' in Brazil) it sort of make me dream to imagine that connecting a keyboard some poor kid could get into development. Obviously I'd rather get a huge screen and powerful computer (and to be honest I make a living making iOS apps) but the idea that this could make it more popular amongst people with much lower revenue is *very* appealing. Of course it can't be Eclipse – this monster – but surely editing a few java and XML files can't require that much horsepower.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions now. I have checked out this app:

[AIDE - Java IDE for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)

... and was fairly impressed. I really think you need an external bluetooth keyboard and mouse to be more productive. If your device has HDMI out or an MHL capable USB output, you can hook it up to a monitor and turn it more into a "Desktop". See here:

[Using a Mobile Device as a Desktop Computer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_--zcmqIyRI)

[Part 2: Using an Android Device as a Desktop](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB-icTl2J-c)

There are some caveats to doing that. For example, my device mirrors the display contents with the internal display's resolution (upscaled). So it is beneficial if your device has the same resolution as your screen, or at least a high enough resolution. Also, a tablet might be more suited, since it runs apps in tablet layout mode, versus a phone layout with everything being too large on a bigger screen. Also noteworthy are the back, home and multitasking buttons. The Galaxy Nexus is currently the only phone implementing these buttons as soft-keys, so they appear on the screen and you can click them with your bluetooth mouse. With a tablet, I think those buttons are always soft-keys, but other phones probably require to reach for the phone and click those buttons. Some of them have keys assigned to them on the keyboard, maybe all of them. Esc is back for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build compiler, aapt, aidl, and other dev tools for Android.
2. Get a standard Java VM running on Android.
3. Get Eclipse running on Android.

I suspect at this point you will find the experience of Eclipse on a current ARM CPU to be...  not so fun. :)

And the general UX is probably not so appropriate right now.  For example, imagine debugging your app in a self-hosted environment.  Without having multiple applications shown on the screen at the same time, this would be pretty painful.

There are already some things allowing simple development on Android, using interpreted languages like Smalltalk, web-based development, etc.  I think we are a bit off from a full traditional Android development environment being self-hosted, but certainly it is fairly safe to assume that at some point it will happen.

Comment: Since when is Eclipse required?  Granted there are substantial difficulties, but that is not one of them.

Comment: If you want to use make and vi, go ahead.  It wouldn't be hard to hack up a basic environment to compile apps.  My point is that putting together enough that you'd actually want to development on that instead of on a desktop is a fair ways off.

Comment: Editing a text file on Android is a far different problem with a range of solutions.  As for a basic environment to compile, I actually think that would be sometimes be useful - for example, if you find a simple mistake while use testing a project away from the development pc.  It would be nice to carry just a tablet and keyboard, and not have to drag a laptop along just for insurance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is nothing available for this or in development at this moment.

I could think that you can create a Android app like the 'App Inventor' from Google for Honeycomb. With the App Inventor you can build a app with simple building blocks.

But a full development environment like Eclipse with the Android SDK will probably never work on a Honeycomb tablet. Development environment work best on large screens (something that you don't have on a tablet, because it's a mobile device) and you need to type a lot of code (something that is not really nice on a touchscreen).

The idea is create and it's a good question, but I don't see it happening anytime soon.